# Question about sets of well-orderings

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I recently posted a question on here about sets of well-orders and isomorphisms between well-orders.  I have a related question about order-type-comparison: if $W$ is any set of well-orders, doesn't order-type-comparison *totally* order this set?  Even if $W$ is composed entirely of singletons, order-type-comparison still totally orders them, right (considering the fact that every well-order has an order-type)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every well-ordered set is order-isomorphic to an ordinal, and every set of ordinals is well-ordered. So if your set $W$ has at most one representative of each (well-)order-type, it will itself be well-ordered. However, if $W$ contains two sets of the same order-type then comparing order-types won't even *partially* order $W$, though it will endow it with a preorder.

Comment: Thanks, Clive - I'm sorry that this is escaping me, but why exactly would having two sets of the same order-type be a problem for order-type-comparison?

Comment: Suppose $X, Y \in W$ have the same order-type and $\le_W$ is order-type comparison; then $X \le_W Y$ and $Y \le_W X$ since $X$ and $Y$ embed into each other. If $\le_W$ were to be a well-order (or total order or partial order) then we'd need $X=Y$ by antisymmetry.

Comment: Ohhh...I think I understand...in my head I was substituting equality with isomorphism here - that would be the wrong way of looking at it, right?

Comment: Right. You'd end up with a well-ordered set if you quotiented out by order-isomorphism (so that isomorphism 'becomes' equality), but as it is, $W$ is not generally a partial order.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much, Clive - that completely clarified things for me!